# Log In directs to homepage even with wrong username and password (PHP/mySql)

Tags: php, mysql

My Log in form works even with the wrong username and password. I have tried searching for answers but I can't find my mistake. Here's the code:

```
<?php
include 'database.php'; ?>

<?php

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['password']);

        $query = "SELECT username, password FROM tbl_membership WHERE username = 
        '$username' AND password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $active = $row['active'];

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
            $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
            header("location: welcome.php");
            exit();
        }if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0){
            echo "Invalid.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Use $count instead of mysqli_num_rows($query) in if

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows($query)`..  `$query` is a string...

Comment: Have you checked your error log? A good idea is also to turn `display_errors` on in your local PHP environment. Read more here: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). That will most likely give you some errors and warnings.

Comment: You should actually rewrite your code using prepared statements (as @Jens suggests) and properly hashing the passwords before you continue. That will drastically change your code so your current issue will most likely not be relevant anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**1:**

Take a look at this line:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
```

The variable `$query` is a string here. You will need to use the `$count` variable you've just set.

```
// Check if we have a result and just one result
if($count == 1) {
```

**2:**

You will only need to get the row contents if it has one result.

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($count == 1) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $active = $row['active'];
}
```

**3:**

Try to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection. Escaping your strings is a good start in this case.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM tbl_membership WHERE username =? AND password =?");

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);

$stmt->execute();
$get_result = $stmt->get_result();
$row_count = $get_result->num_rows;
if ($row_count == 1) {
    $row = $get_result->fetch_assoc();
    $active = $row['active'];
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit();
} else {
    echo "Invalid.";
}
```

**4:**

Don't save the passwords as plain text. This is strongly advised against and creates security issues for your customers/visitors. Use some form of hashing instead. [Read the documentation for more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['password']);

    $query = "SELECT username, password FROM tbl_membership WHERE username = 
    '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);       

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count > 0){
        $_SESSION["username"] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION["password"] = $row['password'];//no need to use password in session
        header("location: welcome.php");

    }else{
        echo "Invalid.";
    }
}
```

Comment: No explanation at all? A good answer includes an explanation about what you've changed, why and how it would solve the issue. Don't just post a block of code since it's not constructive. Btw, the OP shouldn't use this either way since it's not using prepared statements and is still relying on using clear text passwords.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson My teacher told me there were no bad questions and good answers. An answer is valid when it 'answers' the question. Some explanation is pretty usefull though :)

Comment: @Peter Not to be _that_ guy, but I strongly disagree with your teacher. :-)